# Make responsive iframe based on remaining height available with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have a website that has a title, navigation bar, and a paragraph of text, followed by an iframe. I want to set the height of the iframe to the remaining height of the screen and set the iframe width based on this height.

I have a JS function doing it when the website loads, but want to do this using CSS so it is more responsive. [This tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/) shows how to do this based on width of the screen. It makes the height 56.25% of the screen width. I want to do something similar but scale the iframe so it is as large as possible without having users scroll down to see the whole iframe.

In my JS function, I have everything not including the iframe wrapped in `<div class="header">` and get that height with `$('.header').height()`. Then I just subtract this from the window height to get the iframe height and calculate the width based on a ratio (i.e. 16/9 for a video). How can this be done in CSS?

I've tried setting the height to 100% and not specifying the width, which was suggested elsewhere. This didn't work. My iframe is essentially embedding another HTML document, not a video.

Comment: You might find this helpful: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)